# Full width view does not contain same frame width as parent

Tags: ios

I'm having an issue where I have a `UIImageView` that spans the entire width of the screen using the following constraints.

- Align Leading to   : Superview (Equals: -20)
- Align Trailing to  : Superview (Equals: -20)
- Top Space to       : Top Layout Guide (Equals: 0)
- Aspect Ratio       : 1:1

The image assumes the width of the screen while gaining aspect ratio (in this case a square). The issue comes with when I started attempting to make a circle out of the image, that I noticed that my `UIIMageView`'s frames do not have proper values.

You'll have to excuse to code below for not being in Objective-C as I'm using Java through RoboVM but with very little effort you can mentally convert the code to Objective-C as it's pretty straightforward.

```
public class MyViewController extends UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private UIImageView myImageView;

    @Override public void viewDidLoad() {
        System.out.println("Image view width: " + myImageView.getFrame().getWidth());
        System.out.println("Superview width: " + this.getView().getFrame().getWidth());
    }
}
```

The results of running the application with this Controller shows the following:

```
Image view width: 240.0
Superview width: 320.0
```

When cutting the frame width of the image in half and applying that to the `CALayer#cornerRadius` property, the image does not make a complete circle, however when using half of the superviews width (Which is actually the size of the image) the result is a perfect circle.

Comment: im not sure, but u dont have to give aspect ratio constraint . Just leading,trailing,top,bottom are enough

Comment: @Mr.T adding a bottom constraint would cause the image to scale non-proportionally across different device resolutions. This has been tested.

Comment: ohh ok, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad`, it has just loaded your view from the XIB or storyboard, not sized it yet.  The size should be correct when `viewWillAppear` is called.  So try putting your code in `viewWillAppear` and see if that helps.

Comment: This is beautiful, took me a minute to find the method, but it's `viewDidAppear` not `viewWillAppear`, anyway.. thank you heaps for the explanation.

Comment: There should be a `viewWillAppear` as well (at least, there is in Objective-C, haven't used RoboVM myself).  It is called before your view is actually displayed, and thus is useful for perform last-minute quick tweaks to its appearance.  At any rate, yes, the boolean parameter is `animated`.  You'll also want to call `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` before your own implementation as a standard practice.

Comment: Thanks again! You're correct, I finally just found the iOS docs and `viewWillAppear` is there. I guess for now I'll be making all of my changes after the view is displayed. I doubt anyone is going to recognize some microsecond changes, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need the -20 margin is because your superview has a margin of 20, and the constraints are created by default to 'Relative to margin' - if you uncheck that, you can set the 'real' constraint - in this case zero rather than -20

If you select the constraint in the assistant editor, you will see the check box to toggle this value